# Differential equation: NDSolve::berr

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation. I'm able to obtain a solution, and that solution looks more or less as how the theory predict it should be.

```
sol = NDSolve[{1/(b - y[b]) == (
    2 (3 - ((1 - y[b]) (y''[b]))/(y'[b])^2))/(
    1 - 2 (b - (1 - y[b])/y'[b])), y[3/8] == 0, y[1/2] == 1/2}, 
  y[b], {b, 3/8, 1/2}]
```

Unfortunately, I receive from mathematica the following message error:

*The scaled boundary value residual error of 38.. indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified tolerances. Returning the best solution found*

I understand I have to use a shooting method approach, but I'm not familiar with it. I made a try, by adding the following to my code:

*Method -> {"Shooting", 
  "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[3/8] == 10^-8}, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"*

but it did not work (same error message as before). Can someone help me, please?

Comment: The problem arises, because the ODE is singular at `b = 1/2`.